# Importing Python modules when there is a sibling directory with the same name

Tags: python, path, python-import

I have a project structure as follows:

```
python-test » tree
.
├── asdf
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── mycode2.py
│   ├── mycode.py
│   └── scripts
│       └── __init__.py
├── __init__.py
└── scripts
    ├── __init__.py
    └── mymod.py
```

`asdf/mycode.py` contains:

```py
import scripts.mymod
```

and `scripts/mymod.py` contains:

```py
print('hello world')
```

All the `__init__.py`s are empty.

I would like to import `scripts.mymod`.

I am running `asdf/mycode.py` which fails because it is looking inside `asdf/scripts` instead of the root `scripts` folder for `mymod`.

```
> PYTHONPATH=: python asdf/mycode.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asdf/mycode.py", line 1, in <module>
    import scripts.mymod
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts.mymod'
```

As a workaround, I can manually modify the path, which I have done in `asdf/mycode2.py`.

```py
import sys
sys.path = [p for p in sys.path if 'asdf' not in p]
import scripts.mymod
```

This works correctly:

```
> PYTHONPATH=: python asdf/mycode2.py
hello world
```

Is there a way to import `scripts.mymod` in `asdf/mycode.py` **without** modifying the `sys.path` manually, and without changing the `PYTHONPATH` which has to be set to `:`?

Comment: you can use a main entrypoint in the project dir. `python-test/main.py` if you run the code from main dir. you can import with `from asdf.scripts import ...` or `from scripts import mymod`.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Python imports are weird and cumbersome and you are probably best off either creating an entrypoint in the top of the directory or using a tool to handle the path manipulations.

## Python Imports

Python has two different ways of handling imports, the first is the standard: `import numpy as np`, which is resolved against the environment PYTHONPATH in order until it finds the requested module. Included in that path is the directory of the file that is currently being executed, which you see in your example in that you are needing to manually remove that from the `sys.path`.

The other way that python handles imports is via relative paths, which always lead with `.` like `from . import a` or `import .a` or `from .. import b`. Unfortunately, relative import *only* work if the file that they are in is *not* being directly run (This happens if you have two files within a module where one of them imports an object from another, but both of them are intended to be imported by and external script). This is because python uses the builtin **name** global to resolve the relative path, which if the file is being directly run from a shell gets overridden as `"__main__"`.

Consider a file structure:

```
.
├── a.py
└── b.py
```

where `a.py` is

```py
import b
```

and `b.py` is

```py
print(__name__)
```

If you run:

```sh
python3 b.py    # prints "__main__"
python3 a.py    # prints "b"
```

So, if you want to be able to import the `scripts/mymod.py` from `asdf/mycode2.py`, you could put change the import to:

```py
from .. import scripts.mymod
```

But, if you do that, you will *not* be able to run the `asdf/mycode2.py` file directly, you will need to create a third file somewhere else that imports `asdf/mycode2.py` and run that third script (these files are called entrypoints). For example:

```
python-test » tree
.
├── asdf
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── mycode2.py
│   ├── mycode.py
│   └── scripts
│       └── __init__.py
├── __init__.py
├── entrypoint.py
└── scripts
    ├── __init__.py
    └── mymod.py
```

where `entrypoint.py` is

```py
import asdf.mycode2
```

## An Alternative Approach

The alternative approach would be to develop a tool which handles manipulating python's `sys.path` to allow relative imports even when the current file is being run a `"__main__"`. Full disclosure, I am currently working on such a tool based off nodejs's `require` function, called [repyrer](https://github.com/jonathanvanschenck/python-require), which is pip-installable as

```sh
pip3 install repyrer
```

It allows you to do this kind of thing:

```py
from repyrer import repyre

mymod = repyre('../scripts/mymod')
```

which will work even if you run the file directly.

Hope that helps!